# What happens if you declare an array without New in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Array(1) and new Array(1) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827008/whats-the-difference-between-array1-and-new-array1-in-javascript)

In javascript, how are these two different?

```
var arr = Array();  
var arr2 = new Array();
```

If they are the same according to JS standards, are there any browsers that treat both ways differently?

Comment: You might use `var arr = [];` instead.

Comment: And I don't think in this case it does matter, but we'll see what answers come in.

Comment: ... Or, an exact duplicate exists already (big surprise).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to [ECMA-262 edition 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm):

> **15.4.1 The Array Constructor Called as a Function**
>
> When `Array` is called as a function rather than as a constructor,
>    it creates and initialises a new Array object.
>    Thus the function call `Array(...)` is equivalent to the object creation
>    expression `new Array(...)` with the same arguments.

The section **11.1.4** (it is quite long, so I won't quote it) also states that array literal directly corresponds to the `new Array(...)` constructor call.

Comment: ... And the answer is... they are equivalent (according to spec). Correct?

Comment: Nice. Just look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827008/whats-the-difference-between-array1-and-new-array1-in-javascript/5827153#5827153). I hadn't looked at it, honestly!

Comment: What's ECMA-262 edition 5.1? Is it ES5 or ES 10?

Comment: Small sidenote for @Alex - ES10 is not a formal version. Since ES2015 (aka ES6) the official yearly version is ES(year). As of today, the latest version is ES2021 (12th edition).
The above answer is also confirmed by chapter [23.1.1 The Array Constructor](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-array-constructor):
```the function call Array(…) is equivalent to the object creation expression new Array(…) with the same arguments.```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the 2nd is simply proper coding convention, but however Jared has a good point that most people just use `var arr = [];`

Here's a benchmark for your question: http://jsperf.com/array-vs-new-array

After 10 runs, they're neck and neck averaging 65-80 millions ops per second. I see no performance difference whatsoever between the two.

That being said, I added `var arr = [];` to the benchmark, and it is consistently 20-30% faster than the other two, clocking in at well over 120 million ops per second.

Comment: I think you've created a corner case where the optimizer is able to guess a lot. I've tried to avoid that... the test crashes my Chromium somehow, through, so I'll just [show it](http://jsperf.com/array-vs-new-array/2) to illustrate my point.

Comment: Ah okay, it works now. I think that it actually *does* work the way I think it does.