# Order select option with key value by key

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

i'm trying to order alphabetically my list by the key and i'm having problems with that.
i tried to add " | orderBy 'key'" BUT IT DIDIN'T WORK, ANY SUGGESTION?
my html:

```
<label for="select-aspects" class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 control-label">UMS:</label>
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                <select data-smart-select2
                        multiple
                        data-ng-options="key as key for (key, value) in vm.umsAspects "
                        data-ng-disabled="!vm.currentProduct.adoptedListings[vm.currentListingPosition].agentDecisionContract.action || vm.currentProduct.adoptedListings[vm.currentListingPosition].agentDecisionContract.reason!='Aspects'"
                        ng-required="vm.currentProduct.adoptedListings[vm.currentListingPosition].agentDecisionContract.reason=='Aspects'"
                        style="width: 100%;"
                        ng-model="vm.currentProduct.adoptedListings[vm.currentListingPosition].agentDecisionContract.reasonAspects"
                        class="select2"
                        id="select-aspects">
                </select>
              </div>
```

my list looks like this:

> {  Brand: {umsValues: Array(543), multiValue: true, aspectRequired:
>   true}, UPC: {umsValues: Array(543), multiValue: true, aspectRequired:
>   true} Model: {umsValues: Array(543), multiValue: true, aspectRequired:
>   true}, Type: {umsValues: Array(543), multiValue: true, aspectRequired:
>   true} }

in this case i want to display it in the following order:
Brand
Model
Type
UPC

Comment: You are missing a comma before Model.

Comment: You are also calling Array's constructor without new keyword. Should be: new Array(543)

Comment: Using `new` is optional https://stackoverflow.com/a/6893305/2079345