# Why does Array().slice without "new" work?

Tags: javascript

[From here](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#45):

```
function highest(){ 
  return makeArray(arguments).sort(function(a,b){ 
    return b - a; 
  }); 
} 

function makeArray(array){ 
  return Array().slice.call( array ); 
} 

assert(highest(1, 1, 2, 3)[0] == 3, "Get the highest value."); 
assert(highest(3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)[1] == 4, "Verify the results.");
```

Now, why does `Array()` even return something meaningful, without a `new` operator? Most "class" definitions I've seen in JS return `undefined` if called without `new`:

```
function User(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.jump = function() {
    console.log(name + " is jumping!");
  }
}

assert(typeof(User("no New")) == 'undefined');
```

Comment: It's not so much "Why does .slice() work?" as "Why does `Array()` seem to do the same thing as `new Array()`?" - the answer to which can be summed up as "Because the spec says so". See [What's the difference between `Array(1)` and `new Array(1)`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827008/whats-the-difference-between-array1-and-new-array1-in-javascript).

Comment: @nnnnnn - Aye, voted to closed as dup, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.1) explicitly dictates this:

> When `Array` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it creates and initialises a new `Array` object. Thus **the function call `Array(…)` is equivalent to the object creation expression `new Array(…)` with the same arguments**.

How it's done internally depends on the implementation, but for custom constructors you can use the following trick:

```
if(!(this instanceof User)) return new User(name);
```

... because `new User(...)` sets `this` to the created `User` instance, whereas `User(...)` sets it to the global object. (So you were in fact setting global variables in the last snippet.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Chrome's debugging panel, `Array()` returns a new array in the same way that new `Array()` does or that `[]` does. My guess would be that it's either for ease of use of the language, or its related to the `[]` syntax (which of course does not require a new).

It's actually possible with your own functions to optionally require a new:

```
function User(name) {
    if (!(this instanceof User)) {
        return new User(name);
    }
    this.name = name;
    this.jump = function() {
        console.log(name + " is jumping!");
    };
}

​
```

Then both *User('blah')* and *new User('blah')* work.