# When does *not* using new work on built-ins?

Tags: javascript, standards

Playing with built-in JavaScript objects and constructors, I noticed something a little odd.

Sometimes, it's possible to get new objects by calling a constructor without `new`. For example:

```
> new Array(1,2,3,4)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
> Array(1,2,3,4)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But sometimes this doesn't work:

```
> Date()
"Thu Jun 05 2014 00:28:10 GMT-0600 (CST)"
> new Date()
Date 2014-06-05T06:28:10.876Z
```

Is the behavior of non-new constructor built-in functions defined anywhere in the ECMAScript specification? Note that this behavior is actually useful; I can make a non-sparse copy of an array by calling `Array.apply(arr)`, but I'd only feel comfortable doing that if it were cross-platform.

Comment: Another related question with a similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978049/what-values-can-a-constructor-return-to-avoid-returning-this

Comment: Note: `Date() === new Date().toString()`

Comment: [What's the difference between Array(1) and new Array(1) in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827008/whats-the-difference-between-array1-and-new-array1-in-javascript)

Comment: The behaviour for [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is in the docs -> `"Note that JavaScript Date objects can only be instantiated by calling JavaScript Date as a constructor: calling it as a regular function (i.e. without the new operator) will return a string rather than a Date object; unlike other JavaScript object types, JavaScript Date objects have no literal syntax."`

Comment: For Array it's different, it returns a new instance even when called without the new keyword, so it depends on the native method you're using.

Comment: So with builtins, what's the rule? Or is there one? `RegExp` returns a regexp, `Date` returns a string, `Array` returns an array -- aside from `Date`, are there any other built-in constructors that don't return objects?

Comment: P.S. I meant to ask only about built-ins, not about the general behavior of `new`. I edited my question to fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of a native method depends on the EcmaScript specification.

For `Date` [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.2) says :

> When Date is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it
>   returns a String representing the current time (UTC).
>
> NOTE : The function call Date(…) ***is not equivalent*** to the object creation expression new Date(…) with the same arguments.

and for `Array` the [spec says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.1)

> When Array is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it
>   creates and initialises a new Array object.
>
> Thus the function call
>   Array(…) ***is equivalent*** to the object creation expression new Array(…)
>   with the same arguments.

So how it works with or without the `new` keyword is completely dependant on what method you're using, and what the spec says should happen when called without the new keyword.

For instance, the Math object is different again

> The Math object does not have a [[Construct]] internal property; it is
>   not possible to use the Math object as a constructor with the new
>   operator.

Comment: It would be nice if you could add the behavior of all the built-ins as functions vs. constructors (there are not so many). The reference to the spec is very nice.

Comment: @user3629476 - Well, there's Date, Array, Object, String, Number, Boolean, Math, RegExp etc. there's quite a few, and the spec says it all, I'm not sure if copying the spec for every built-in would make the answer any better ?

Comment: Not to mention at you'd have to update he answer for ES6, ES7, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (I am using 5.1 Edition for reference) does define how should object constructors behave when called with or without the `new` keyword.

For `Array`:

[15.4.1 The Array Constructor Called as a Function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.1):

> When `Array` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it creates and initialises a new Array object. Thus the function call `Array(…)` is equivalent to the object creation expression `new Array(…)` with the same arguments.

[15.4.2 The Array Constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.2):

> When `Array` is called as part of a `new` expression, it is a constructor: it initialises the newly created object.

For `Date`:

[15.9.2 The Date Constructor Called as a Function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.2):

> When `Date` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it returns a String representing the current time (UTC).
>   The function call `Date(…)` is not equivalent to the object creation expression `new Date(…)` with the same arguments.

[15.9.3 The Date Constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3):

> When `Date` is called as part of a new expression, it is a constructor: it initialises the newly created object.